# iOS: insert attributed string at cursor for UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

`UITextView` lets you insert plain text at the cursor with the `insertText` function. Is there a clean way to do so with attributed text?

Is the only approach to split the `attributedText` property into two parts -- pre-cursor and post-cursor -- then append the new attributed string to the pre-cursor attributed text, followed by appending the post-cursor attributed text?

Comment: I guess: Create a  `NSMutableAttributedString` named `tempAttributedString` from `myTextView.attributedText`. Get the range from the `selectedRange`. Use `replaceCharacters(in:with:)` to insert in that range. If the range length is 0, then it's an "insert", else it's a replace (even if it's a replace in both cases). Set that tempAttributedStringText to `myTextView.AttributedText`. Reposition the `selectedRange` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert into a mutable copy of the text view’s attributed text by calling https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414947-insert.

Comment: Thanks so much! Posted an answer inspired by your response, but obviously gave you credit.

Answer (score 1):

As advised by @matt, here's a Swift 4.x function:

```
fileprivate func insertAtTextViewCursor(attributedString: NSAttributedString) {
    // Exit if no selected text range
    guard let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange else {
        return
    }

    // If here, insert <attributedString> at cursor
    let cursorIndex = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
    let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    mutableAttributedText.insert(attributedString, at: cursorIndex)
    textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
}
```

Comment: it will cause all new inputs become part of this link, how can i solve it?